# How to NOT share conditional symbols in large teams?

Tags: visual-studio, svn, visual-studio-2012, ignore, collaboration

We use SVN with VS2012. **I have a bit of code which I want to be compiled for myself only**. I defined conditional compilation symbol and used #if pragma..

However it appeared to be shared through the project file and the SVN with everyone which defies the purpose.

How do you guys go about this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yeah... any changes you make to the file get checked in - svn, doesn't know anything about the code itself.  If it's for you only, don't check it in on a branch anyone else uses.

Comment: it is section of a method and I need this part to be run when I work on it.. I cant separate it from the method itself.. Its like normal if - if that is me run this branch not that...